# DataContractJsonSerializer on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to serialize an object into JSON in Silverlight on Windows Phone 7. My problem is, and this sounds stupid: I can't find it. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28VS.95%29.aspx), it should work and be available on WP7.

Can somebody help me? This is stopping me at this point. I haven't been able to get beyond this :(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is your project referencing the dll "System.ServiceModel.Web" ?

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. I kept trying to reference the wrong damn assembly. Seriously, you saved me from going nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sharp serializer. It's fast and works great on windows phone. There is a tutorial over at http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-sharpserializer/